# Iteration over enum in ngFor not working in Firefox

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular with typescript to create frontend for my app.

I have created an select element where I create options:

```
   <mat-option
        [value]="ift"
        *ngFor='let ift  of inputFileTypes | elements'>
        {{ "generator.inputFileType." + ift | translate}}
    </mat-option>
```

in which I am using pipe to get all elements of my Enum

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'elements'
})
export class EnumElementsPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(data: Object) {
      return Object.keys(data);
    }
}
```

inputFileTypes is an enum (in component.ts: `inputFileTypes = InputFileType`)

```
export enum InputFileType {
    TYPE1= 'TYPE1',
    TYPE2= 'TYPE2'
}
```

This creates my select with options perfectly well in Chrome and Opera, but does not work on Firefox. No errors, but options are not created. Any idea why?

Comment: You have `return = Object.keys(data);` in the `transform` method instead of `return Object.keys(data);`. Is it a typo in the question?

Comment: Yes, it is typo in the question

Comment: It works for me in Firefox (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vnkqe8)).

Comment: [It works for me in Firefox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1nr7fm?file=app/select-overview-example.ts). Which version of Angular are you using? Would you mind providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You can use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to create one.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You have helped me to determinate that the problem was somewhere else.

Comment: mat-option was nested in mat-button. This cause a rendering problem in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version of angular >= 6.1.x, you could simplify this by using the [`KeyValuePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) as follows:

```
<mat-option
        [value]="ift"
        *ngFor='let ift  of inputFileTypes | keyvalue'>
        {{ "generator.inputFileType." + ift.key| translate}}
    </mat-option>
```

Which has no issues in firefox, see [the following stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h5ssvp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you for your help. You have helped me to determinate that the problem was somewhere else.